# Canvas Paint: Draw shadow only on the left and right side

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas, paint

I'm drawing a rectangle on a canvas and I want to add a shadow/glow on the left and right side but **not** at the top and bottom. The `BlurMaskFilter` would be an alternative but it affects both axis too.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShadowLayer(10, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
//paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));

Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up erasing those areas by drawing a new `Rect` with `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` on top of the shadows.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

Comment: Hi, this was helpful and works! just wondering ,didn't find any better solution for it yet?

Comment: @ErfanDP Well, I changed some stuff around. Don't really know if it's better but now I'm using canvas.clipPath()